# Android avd not launching from avd device manager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-6.0-marshmallow, react-native, nexus-6p

Working with a fresh install of ubuntu 17 & fresh install of androidstudio2.3.1

I am using android studio to manage the creation of a new avd, and am able to navigate to the avd manager and create a new device (i chose a Nexus 6)
The virtual device should be running android Marshmallow.

The new avd then shows in the device manager, but when using the 'green arrow' to launch the device in the emulator, nothing seems to happen. Tried all the usual solutions, restarts etc.

EDIT: I should add that android studio is installed in /opt/

Has anyone experienced this? Any solutions or help on how to fix this issue appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Under the virtual device configuration try changing the option under Emulated performance->Graphics from automatic to hardware or software.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have tried with both hardware/software emulated performance, and still nothing happens. any other suggestions?

Comment: @ste do you have any error messages in the 'event log' panel?

Comment: no messages in the event log. when i click to launch the avd, the progress bar at the bottom of android studio appears, and completes, but then nothing else happens.

Comment: how about in the 'Run' panel, next to 'Android Monitor'

Comment: nothing in that panel either. It seems to start the avd, but it never fully executed and no avd appears on screen.